# How to find number of values over a certain cell in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R that looks like:

```
              percent
 Input_SNP      9.123
 Set_1          8.713
 Set_2          7.666
 Set_3          7.091
 Set_4          7.601
 Set_5          5.461
 Set_6          9.992
 Set_7          5.555
```

Except I don't have the period over `Input_SNP`. It's class "data.frame" when I call `class(data)`. I actually have 500 sets. I want to calculate what proportion of sets have a value greater than or equal to my `Input_SNP`. In this example 1 out of the 7 has a value greater than or equal to my `Input_SNP`. I would like an output variable with this value. How can this be done in R?

Comment: `prop.table( table( data$percent[-1] >= data$percent[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is called `df`, then you can do

```
inp <- rownames(df) == "Input_SNP"
with(df, percent[!inp] > percent[inp])
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This shows one `TRUE` value.  To get the total number of `TRUE` values we can do

```
with(df, sum(percent[!inp] > percent[inp]))
# [1] 1
```

For the values themselves, we can do

```
with(df, percent[!inp][percent[!inp] > percent[inp]])
# [1] 9.992
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(percent = c(9.123, 8.713, 7.666, 7.091, 7.601, 
5.461, 9.992, 5.555)), .Names = "percent", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Input_SNP", 
"Set_1", "Set_2", "Set_3", "Set_4", "Set_5", "Set_6", "Set_7"
))
```

Comment: This is great except the final `with(df, percent[!np][percent[!inp] > percent[inp]])` gave me multiple values?

Comment: this is smaller additional question. I'm now just using `p <- with(df, sum(percent[!inp] > [percent[inp]))/(nrow(df)-1)` I know what to print the value p in a graph. If the p-value is 0 though then I want p to equal 0.002. How can I do that?

Comment: In regard to your first comment, it will give you multiple values when there are multiple values over `percent[inp]`.  Are you looking for the sum?

Comment: I was able to correctly get it. I wanted the proportion that had values higher. Thanks! What about my follow-up, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- df$percent[rownames(df) == "Input_SNP"]
ifelse(df >= x, 1, 0)
#             percent
#Input_SNP       0
#Set_1           0
#Set_2           0
#Set_3           0
#Set_4           0
#Set_5           0
#Set_6           1
#Set_7           0
```